# Content out of order in Blazor when using the MarkupString

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to build a component to wrap up display of content in different html elements (TD or TH).

In this simplified example, I have two MarkupString casts from string methods with a content included between them...

```
@((MarkupString)GetStartingMarkup())
@GetContent()
<span>Inner Content</span>
@((MarkupString)GetEndingMarkup())

@code {

    private string GetStartingMarkup(){
        return "<span class=\"example\">";
    }

    private string GetContent(){
        return "Content";
    }
    
    private string GetEndingMarkup(){
        return "</span>";
    }
}
```

I am expecting when this gets displayed to have...

```
<span class="example">
Content
<span>Inner Content</span>
</span>
```

Instead, the content appears outside the span tag...

```
<span class="example"></span>
<!--!-->
Content
<!--!-->
<!--!-->
<span>Inner Content</span>
```

The content between the markup strings needs to be editable as the final version will include logic to embed other html and components

Any ideas how to get the intended behaviour?

Comment: I am not sure what you trying to build, but using markup string for opening and closing element seems like too much unnecessary work. You should either use components or inline RenderFragments.

Comment: Without posting a lot more code, the intention is to control what element type is used for the enclosing tag. In the example I use span but want to build it out so I can switch between TD and TH in a table layout. I can (and have) moved that logic into a component but am currently now left with ugly repeating code - I think I can work that away using the answer given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render engine auto closes your element.

`DynamicElement.cs`

This component takes the element name and uses attribute splatting.

```
public class DynamicElement : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public string ElementName { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(sequence: 0, ElementName);
        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(sequence: 1, Attributes);
        builder.AddContent(sequence: 2, ChildContent);
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
<DynamicElement ElementName="span" class="example">
    @GetContent()
</DynamicElement>
@code {
    private string GetContent()
    {
        return "Content";
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
<!--!-->
<span class="example">Content</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian - that is a nice reusable solution. Specifically in my scenario I want to avoid the ChildContent as I have a specific permitted nested component, but the fundamentals are here and I can play around with that. Cheers again